# Is there a way to add meta tag like open graph on my API?

Tags: json, seo, meta-tags

I have a mobile app that has share functionality. I want the link that will shared from my app will has some preview like the name of my app and a picture of it not just plain link.

I have learn about open graph specification, but I found that it just work with web pages because they have meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

For APIs, include Open Graph-like metadata either in the JSON response body or as custom headers. Embed metadata directly in the response JSON or use headers like X-Open-Graph-Title and X-Open-Graph-Image. Alternatively, create a separate endpoint for metadata.